# List top ten hashtags

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop, preg-replace

Currently this query only outputs one result from the database and I'm needing it to show the top ten results by the amount of times a tag has been posted.

So if #stackoverflow is tagged in a post 8 times and stackexchange is post 6 I would have

> 1.Stackoverflow
>
> 8 posts
>
> 2.stackexchange
>
> 6 posts

and so on up to ten results. currently i only have one returned hashtag result and I have 2 posts with the same hashtag, yet its only showing one record and says 1 post when it show one record and 2 posts.. and also more than record if there is more than one different hashtag in my database.

I have added while to my tags, its clear there isn't a while loop within my code and I'm wondering whether its this that is missing!

```
<? 
  $chantj = mysqli_query($mysqli, $callj);
  $num = mysqli_num_rows($chantj);
  $calltrendingj = "SELECT streamitem_content,streamitem_id,
                            COUNT(streamitem_content) AS total
                    FROM streamdata
                    WHERE streamitem_content LIKE '%#%'
                    GROUP BY streamitem_content 
                    ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 10";

  $chanttrendingj = mysqli_query($mysqli, $calltrendingj);
  if (!$chanttrendingj) {
      printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($mysqli));
      exit();
  }
  $numtrendingj = mysqli_num_rows($chanttrendingj);
  for($i=1; $numrowscountj = mysqli_fetch_array($chanttrendingj); $i++)
  {
      $conttrend = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,stripslashes($numrowscountj['streamitem_content']));
      $autoembedtrend = new AutoEmbed();
      $conttrend = $autoembedtrend->parse($conttrend);
      $regextrend = "/#+([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/"; 
      $conttrend = preg_replace($regextrend, '<a href="hash.php?tag=$1">$0</a>', $conttrend); 
      $conttrend=substr($conttrend, 0, strrpos($conttrend, ' '));
      $conttrend = str_replace('#', '', $conttrend); 
  ?>
  Trending<br><hr>
  <h2><? echo $conttrend; ?></h2>
        <? if($numtrendingj==1){?>
  <h5><? echo $numtrendingj?> Post</h5>
        <? }else if($numtrendingj>1){ ?>
  <h5><? echo $numtrendingj ?> Posts</h5>
        <? } ?>
  <br>
  <? }  ?>
```

Comment: `GROUP by '%#%'` that's most bizarre. You figure you'd want to do `GROUP BY column` and doubt you have a column of a similar name, do you?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script and see the errors flow

Comment: you can ping me on the flipside

Comment: You might want to check on the results of those queries in the mysql console...

Comment: So say I post `#testing` twice to database in two separate posts, how would I then group them so it would output `testing 2 posts`!

Comment: `GROUP BY streamitem_content` and forget the where clasue

Comment: I've updated the query code up above. I am getting all outputted posts now but if say I have two #testing its printing out twice instead of grouping them.

Comment: Right okay, I've found a better solution. To take the hashtags from the posts and store them into a separate table and do trending that way as per an idea by this [link](http://webdevrefinery.com/forums/topic/7718-logic-behind-trending/)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I never really bothered with `mysqli` but does `mysqli_report()` bring any usefull material to the table that `mysqli_error()` doesnt? I'm asking because the docs are not really clear on this subject.

Comment: There is absolutely no errors what so ever. I believe its just the query that needs to find all the hashed words in the streamitem_content column and then group them so if user1 has post #testing hello and user 2 has posted #testing hello there.. then it will output #testing once as the top result as #testing been posted twice.